# MariaDB Server won't start

Tags: mysql, mariadb

i have some trouble with my MariaDB Server - it won't start anymore.
Everytime i start try to start the server it failed:

```
root# /etc/init.d/mysql start
[....] Starting mysql (via systemctl): mysql.service
Job for mysql.service failed. See 'systemctl status mysql.service' and 
'journalctl -xn' for details.
failed!
```

I already tried this:

- rebooting the whole system
- restarting the mysql service (normal and in safe mode) -> start failed
- checking permissions of /var/lib/mysqld
- reinstalling MariaDB adding *innodb_force_recovery = 6* to my.cnf

Here is my lates Log-File:

```
170716 19:27:14 [Note] InnoDB: Using mutexes to ref count buffer pool pages
170716 19:27:14 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
170716 19:27:14 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
170716 19:27:14 [Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin __atomic_thread_fence() is used for memory barrier
170716 19:27:14 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
170716 19:27:14 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
170716 19:27:14 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
170716 19:27:14 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
170716 19:27:14 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
170716 19:27:14 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
170716 19:27:14 [Note] InnoDB: The log sequence numbers 4530292 and 4530292 in ibdata files do not match the log sequence number 5818903 in the ib_logfiles!
170716 19:27:14 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!
170716 19:27:14 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
170716 19:27:14 [Note] InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
170716 19:27:14 [Note] InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages 
170716 19:27:14 [Note] InnoDB: from the doublewrite buffer...
InnoDB: Error: trying to access page number 4294896896 in space 0,
InnoDB: space name ./ibdata1,
InnoDB: which is outside the tablespace bounds.
InnoDB: Byte offset 0, len 16384, i/o type 10.
InnoDB: If you get this error at mysqld startup, please check that
InnoDB: your my.cnf matches the ibdata files that you have in the
InnoDB: MySQL server.
2017-07-16 19:27:14 76f26000  InnoDB: Assertion failure in thread 1995595776 in file fil0fil.cc line 5612
InnoDB: We intentionally generate a memory trap.
InnoDB: Submit a detailed bug report to http://bugs.mysql.com.
InnoDB: If you get repeated assertion failures or crashes, even
InnoDB: immediately after the mysqld startup, there may be
InnoDB: corruption in the InnoDB tablespace. Please refer to
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: about forcing recovery.
170716 19:27:14 [ERROR] mysqld got signal 6 ;
This could be because you hit a bug. It is also possible that this binary
or one of the libraries it was linked against is corrupt, improperly built,
or misconfigured. This error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.

To report this bug, see https://mariadb.com/kb/en/reporting-bugs

We will try our best to scrape up some info that will hopefully help
diagnose the problem, but since we have already crashed, 
something is definitely wrong and this may fail.

Server version: 10.0.30-MariaDB-0+deb8u2
key_buffer_size=134217728
read_buffer_size=131072
max_used_connections=0
max_threads=153
thread_count=0
It is possible that mysqld could use up to 
key_buffer_size + (read_buffer_size + sort_buffer_size)*max_threads = 465934 K  bytes of memory
Hope that's ok; if not, decrease some variables in the equation.

Thread pointer: 0x0
Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
terribly wrong...
stack_bottom = 0x0 thread_stack 0x30000
The manual page at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/crashing.html contains
information that should help you find out what is causing the crash.
addr2line: 'mysqld': No such file
```

I have no clue what to do next.
Every recovery guide i could find just backuped the ibd* files and the schematics-directory, startet the server with *innodb_force_recovery = 6* or *innodb_force_recovery = 4* and everything worked again for them.

Has anybody an Idea?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Try using innodb_force_recovery = 1 and exporting the dump. After the expore is complete, store a copy of and remove the ib*-files in /var/lib/mysql. You should be able to restart mariadb without innodb_force_recovery after that, and import the dump.

Comment: thanks for your replay but sadly `innodb_force_recovery = 1` wont help starting the server. I still got the same errors in the error-logs as above

Comment: Have you solved this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem. Check your systems date and timezone information. using **timedatectl** command. Server I was using ntp is active by default Make NTP disabled and set date and timezone correct. reboot it everything will be fine. Hope that might help.

Answer (score -1):

Try to run mysql with alternately from **innodb_force_recovery = 1** to **innodb_force_recovery = 6**.
When mysql starts up try to mysqldump your databases and restore it on test node.
If all OK try to restore dump on production node without **innodb_force_recovery** parameter.

Before restoring backup **/var/lib/mysql** directory.